# uwp upload operation progress.status = error

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, image-uploading

I have an UploadOperation and I want to restart it after app start. It has a BytesSend value > 0 and the progress.status value is Error. If I try to AttchAsync than I get "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EF1".

What can I do to restart the UploadOperation? I don't know which image to upload because my upload.SourceFile == null.

thanx newone

Comment: I'm in the same situation. So far i understood:
1. 0x80072EF1 - WININET_E_OPERATION_CANCELLED
2. If the app is restarted after termination and operations from the previous session are not enumerated and re-attached to the current session, they will remain incomplete and continue to occupy resources. Once enumerated, PUT upload operations are automatically restarted, and POST upload operations are terminated.
Maybe in your case is enough to make it PUT. In my case it must be POST :(